# Алгоритм вычисления координат обрезки изображения

Tags: c++, qt

Есть изображение размером 5470 на 3646 (например) пикселей. Оно выводится пользователю в окно размером 831 на 554, то есть с масштабированием по осям 6. Далее пользователю дается возможность вырезать нужный ему кусок изображения. Вот как я это делаю:

```
rect = imageLabel->getCuttingSquare();
qDebug() << "MainWindow::makeCrop square width = " << rect.width() << " height = " << rect.height();

rect.getCoords(&rX1, &rY1, &rX2, &rY2);
rect.setCoords(rX1*coeffX, rY1*coeffY, rX2*coeffX, rY2*coeffY);

cropImage = ethalonImage.copy(rect);
```

В итоге вырезается совсем другой кусок, находящийся выше и левее вырезанного.

Для выделения области используется QRubberBand. Изображение грузится в перегруженный QLabel, вставленный в QScrollArea. Qt 5.5.1, MSVC 2013.

Comment: Вроде все правильно выглядит. Берем все мини-координаты и скейлим их ...

Comment: Тем не менее, вырезается другой кусок...

Comment: Отладчик и листик бумажки с карандашом в помощь! Рисуйте какие координаты приходят, какие получаются.

Comment: Думается, стоит копать в сторону используемых систем координат и функций `mapTo... и mapFrom...`.

Comment: может нужно учитывать отступы scroll area?